# Hardhat & Metamask not showing imported custom token

Tags: solidity, metamask, hardhat

I have a custom ERC20 deployed on Hardhat. I set a random token balance on 10 Hardhat accounts, which have all been imported into Metamask. A call to balanceOf in the contract confirms the account balances are correct. In Metamask I imported the contract address under "import tokens", and I see the correct token balance for the first two Hardhat accounts, but the other eight accounts don't show the imported token at all.

When I click "import tokens" for these other eight accounts, and enter the contract address, it shows the token name and balance correctly, then I confirm by clicking "Import tokens" and the token doesn't appear in the token list.

I'm using Metamask 10.23.2 and Hardhat 2.12.5. My Hardhat chain ID is 1337 (not 31337) and I believe the two Hardhat accounts showing the token are doing so because I previously added the token to these two accounts weeks ago. Something has changed and I now can't add the same token to other Hardhat accounts.

Can anyone offer any advice on this problem?

Comment: did you try doing settings -> advanced -> reset account and still have the issue?

Comment: Yes, it made no difference. I have since discovered that Metamask has removed support for chain 1337, I'm getting the error: “TokenService Error: ChainId 0x539 is not supported”. I didn't see it before because you have to go to "import account" after trying to add a token to see the error. This explains the two accounts where my token is showing, I added the token to these accounts some time ago when chain 1337 was supported.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by simply using the standard Hardhat chain ID 31337 and everything works, seems like the Metamask bug is fixed and it now works fine with this chain ID.